# Undefined property from imported Class

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

This is my first time with Webpack and ES6 modules. After bundling modules, at the beginning, it looks like the script loaded everything correctly, beacouse get methods return class property correctly, for example: Avaliable points: 5. But when I click "+" button `init.getAvaliablePoints()` and `init.getHealthPoints()` methods return `NaN`, when i click "-" return `undefined`. So, it seems that `InitGame()` propertys are `undefined`. Why?

Part of index.js:

```js
//index.js
'use strict';
import InitGame from './InitGame.js';
import Game from './Game.js';

let init = new InitGame();

const creator = document.getElementById("creator");
const mainMenu = document.getElementById("main");

creator.innerHTML =
        `<h1>Create Character:</h1>
        <h3 id="points">Avaliable points: ${init.getAvaliablePoints()}</h3>
        <div class="stats">
            <div class="health">
                <button id="minusH" type="button">-</button>
                <span id="healthPoints">Health: ${init.getHealthPoints()}</span>
                <button id="plusH" type="button">+</button>
            </div>     
        </div>`;

document.querySelector("#minusH").addEventListener('click', init.removeHealthPoints);
document.querySelector("#plusH").addEventListener('click', init.addHealthPoints);
```

Part of InitGame.js:

```js
//InitGame.js
export default class InitGame {
    constructor(){
        this.avaliablePoints = 5;
        this.healthPoints = 10;
        this.dmgPoints = 10;
        this.stats = undefined;
}

removeHealthPoints() {
        if (this.healthPoints >= 11) {
            this.avaliablePoints += 1;
            this.healthPoints -= 1;
        }
        else {
            console.log("10 health points is minimum");
        }
        document.getElementById("healthPoints").innerHTML = "Health: " + this.healthPoints;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Avaliable points: " + this.avaliablePoints;
}

addHealthPoints() {
        if (this.avaliablePoints == 0) {
            console.log("0 avaliablePoints");
        }
        else {
            this.avaliablePoints -= 1;
            this.healthPoints += 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("healthPoints").innerHTML = "Health: " + this.healthPoints;
        document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = "Avaliable points: " + this.avaliablePoints;
}
getAvaliablePoints() {
        return this.avaliablePoints;
}
getHealthPoints() {
        return this.healthPoints;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the properties are undefined, it's that `this` is not set properly when you click on the buttons. You're just passing the method function to `addEventListener`, but not binding it to the `init` object. As a result, within the functions `this` is set to the event target.

You can use the `bind()` method to bind it to the `init` object.

```
document.querySelector("#minusH").addEventListener('click', init.removeHealthPoints.bind(init));
document.querySelector("#plusH").addEventListener('click', init.addHealthPoints.bind(init));
```